# Looking for an SMD fuse spare part marked with "PP"

Tags: identification, surface-mount, fuses

I am bit out of ideas for this SMD fuse marked with "PP", where I can only find "P" ones. It's about 2x1mm in size. Does anyone have a clue what that is? Maybe its no fuse, after all ;) Thanks!

[image: Picture of unknown fuse]

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you provided a photo of the component. along with its dimensions.

Comment: Sure, here you are: https://imgur.com/a/SnvVtRX - Its about 2x1mm in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a [Bourns MF-PSML300](https://www.ttieurope.com/content/dam/tti-europe/manufacturers/bourns/resources/mfpsml.pdf) PTC resettable fuse.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, I will check! :)

Comment: It seems to make sense in this case, as this is an electric toothbrush the motor probably can draw a few 1-2 amps at low voltage. I will mark the question as answered.